# How do I terminate the while loop by an input character "q"

Tags: c, loops

This is the while loop and I would like to stop the loop a character 'q' is typed as an input. So when "Please enter the five requirements" appears and I type in q then it stops running

```
while (1)
  {
      printf("Please enter the five requirements:");
      scanf("%d %f %f %d %d", &my, &mii, &mr, &ml, &mp);
      printf("You entered: %d %f %f %d %d\n", my, mii, mr, ml, mp);
      for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
      {
          if (my <= mortGage[i].min_d && mii >= mortGage[i].max_iin && mr >= mortGage[i].max_rt &&
              ml <= mortGage[i].min_l && mp >= mortGage[i].max_pf)
          {
              printf("name is : %s\n", mortGage[i].name_b);
              printf("min duration is : %d\n", mortGage[i].min_d);
              printf("max initial rate is : %f\n", mortGage[i].max_iin);
              printf("max rate is : %f\n", mortGage[i].max_rt);
              printf("min loan is : %d\n", mortGage[i].min_l);
              printf("max product fees is : %d\n", mortGage[i].max_pf);
              printf("\n");
          }
          else
          {
              printf("");
          }
      //if (my == 'q'|| mii == 'q' || mr == 'q' || ml == 'q' || mp == 'q')
          //break;
      }

  }
```

Comment: `%d` can only read an integer, you can't enter `q` there.

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read a line of input. Check if the line begins with `q`. If it does, break out of the loop. Otherwise, use `sscanf()` to parse the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it can help you. This is what I do here:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int check;
    while (1)
    {
      printf("Please enter the five requirements:");
      check=scanf("%d %f %f %d %d", &my, &mii, &mr, &ml, &mp);
      if(checker==0){
        printf("Input Q\n");
        break;
      }else{
        printf("You entered: %d %f %f %d %d\n", my, mii, mr, ml, mp);
        for (i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
          if (my <= mortGage[i].min_d && mii >= mortGage[i].max_iin && mr >= mortGage[i].max_rt &&
              ml <= mortGage[i].min_l && mp >= mortGage[i].max_pf)
          {
              printf("name is : %s\n", mortGage[i].name_b);
              printf("min duration is : %d\n", mortGage[i].min_d);
              printf("max initial rate is : %f\n", mortGage[i].max_iin);
              printf("max rate is : %f\n", mortGage[i].max_rt);
              printf("min loan is : %d\n", mortGage[i].min_l);
              printf("max product fees is : %d\n", mortGage[i].max_pf);
              printf("\n");
          }else{
              printf("");
          }
      }
      }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to print the mortgages in increasing order of of mortGage[i].max_iin ; how would I do that?